# while true loop in python can't be stopped

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, indentation

I have a problem with this loop in python:

```
i = 1
while True:
    with open('/tmp/file.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            work = 'word1' + line + 'word2' + line + 'counter=' + str(i) + 'test'
            result = Function()
            if "statement" in result:
                out = open('/tmp/result.txt', 'a+')
                out.write(result)
                out.close()
                i = i + 10
            else:
                return i
```

I want first read file.txt line by line and then for each line count `i` till statement exists in result but this loop is infinitive... So I removed `break` and used `return i` instead. but no result

How can I tell the while True loop to be stopped when all lines from file.txt is read and for each line counter is completed?

## UPDATE

what I want to process:

```
word1line1word2line1counter=1test
word1line1word2line1counter=2test
word1line1word2line1counter=3test
.
.
.
#`till my if condition is true` then
word1line2word2line2counter=1test
word1line2word2line2counter=2test
word1line2word2line2counter=3test
.
.
.
and so on
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using the `while` loop *at all*? The `for` loop will loop over the lines of the file; what else do you want to loop? And what does `Function` do?

Comment: Just want to read lines in `file.txt` and set i sounter for each line/// Can you help me?

Comment: Please choose one indentation level ([preferably 4 spaces](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) and then stick with it.

Comment: @MortezaLSC could you describe what this algorithm is supposed to be doing? Again, what does `Function` do? What is `work` for? What will `result` actually be? At the moment it is very difficult to help because your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Ffisegydd Note that your edit *might* have hidden the real problem: if the ,`return` isn't executed it might be because the mix of tabs and spaces causes the `else` block to be attached to the `for` loop, instead of the `if`. Do not edit the code provided except if you are 100% sure that the change is innocuous. The OP should try to reindent the code from the start to verify this.

Comment: @Bakuriu I did not edit the code, only asked the OP to choose one indentation level and stick with it :) but I know the person who did and will point him towards your comment.

Comment: @MortezaLSC you still don't say what `Function` does. Why doesn't it have any arguments? What does it return? Should `i` be 1, 11, 21, ... for each line? At the moment, it keeps increasing.

Comment: get the content of url from a web site

Comment: @MortezaLSC so how is that at all related to `work` and `i`?!

Comment: @Ffisegydd Oh, sorry. I saw the edit of Peter and your comment and for some reason thought that you were the same person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
out = open('/tmp/result.txt', 'a+')
with open('/tmp/file.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
                i = 1
                line=line.strip('\r\n ')
                while True:
                        work = 'word1' + line + 'word2' + line + 'counter=' + str(i) + 'test'
                        print work
                        result = Function()
                        if "statement" in result:
                                out.write(result)
                                i += 10
                        else:
                                break
out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to switch your loops around:

```
i = 1
with open('/tmp/file.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        result = ...
        while "statement" in result:
            with open('/tmp/result.txt', 'a+') as out:
                out.write(result)
            i += 10
            result = ...
```

Although it is not at all clear what this algorithm is supposed to be doing